# COUNTIF Multiple Lookup (Vertical, Horizontal)

Tags: excel-formula

I have the following data:

```
       wk12 wk12 wk12 wk12 wk12
user1        OOO  OOO  OOO
user2
user3
user4
```

I am looking to write a formula that based on both the header (horizontal) and user (and specific value in the matched fields), to return the counted values of "OOO".

I was attempting COUNTIF(INDEX(MATCH(MATCH  without success and have also tried SUMPRODUCT without success. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:F1=D8)*(A2:A5=D7)*(B2:F5="OOO"))
```

[image]